# I accidentally deleted files in a repository using rm *$*

Tags: shell, rm

I was trying to remove a file within a repository which contained a "$" symbol, so I used:

```
rm *$*
```

But this deleted all my files in the directory and attempted to delete all subdirectories as well.

Can someone explain why this command did not just remove files containing a `$`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. If you're writing a shell script asking about that is on topic, but general command-line usage questions should be posted to [unix.se] or [su] instead.

Comment: As noted, not a good question for SO.  But here's a tip: Before doing a `rm` command, try it first as `ls` (with the same args you'll give to rm) and see that the files you want to delete are the ones listed (and no others).  Then edit the command to replace `ls` with `rm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*$*` first undergoes parameter expansion, with `$*` expanding to a string consisting of all the current positional parameters. If there are none, the result is `*`, which *then* undergoes pathname expansion.

The correct command would have been something like `rm *"$"*` or `rm *\$*`, with the `$` escaped to prevent any parameter expansion from taking place before pathname expansion.

Comment: This makes sense. My mistake was assuming parameter expansions with $ always require open/close brackets.

Comment: Like `${*}`? That's always *legal*, but they can be dropped when their is no ambiguity about what the variable name is (compare `$foobar` and `${foo}bar`) or when no operator is used (`$foo` vs `${foo%txt}`).